# Range of an increasing function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

**Statement**: If $y=f(x)$ is increasing in $ [\alpha , \beta]$ then it's range is $[f(\alpha),f(\beta)]$

My Answer: Yes, it should be.

Actual Answer: No it need not be true always.

Where am i going wrong, if we see graphically, then this statement should be true, but it's not. Need help.

Comment: Range is contained in $[f(\alpha), f(\beta)]$. It need not  be the whole of this interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that, nowhere has it been stated that the function must be continuous. A discontinuous, and increasing function will not take all values in that range.

Comment: I haven't read about continuous function yet, but I know a thing or two about it. Do  we consider a discontinuous function as a increasing function?

Comment: Yes we can. A discontinuous function, at some point 
$x=a$, means that the statement: $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=f(a)$ is false. This has no corelation with whether or not $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Consider, for example, the function: $$y=x,0\leq x\leq1$$ $$y=x+1, 1<x \leq 2$$ This function is increasing and discontinuous at $x=1$.

Comment: In place of saying that the range is contained in $[\alpha,\ \beta]$, could we say that a subset of the range lies in the interval $[\alpha,\ \beta]$ ?

Comment: @rks yes, i think you are right., but the interval is [f(α),f(β)].

Comment: I think you mean to ask-"Will the range lie in a subset of $[f(\alpha), f(\beta)]$?" The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)$ be $x$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$ and $x+1$ in $(1,2]$ the function is increasing but its range is not $[0,3]$ because it does not hit $1.1$ for example